# Casting generic delegated to non generic with the same signature

Tags: c#, generics, compiler-construction, delegates, type-conversion

This must be a simply question. I define two delegate types:

```
delegate void TestHandler(object sender, EventArgs args);
delegate void TestHandlerGen<TArgs>(object sender, TArgs args);
```

Then I use them:

```
TestHandler h1 = null;
TestHandlerGen<EventArgs> h2 = delegate { };

// this compiles
h1 = new TestHandler(h2);

// this doesn't compile:
// Cannot implicitly convert type 'X.TestHandlerGen<System.EventArgs>' 
// to 'X.TestHandler'
h1 = h2;
```

The delegeates have the same signature, why does `h1 = h2` not compile?

Why does `h1 = new TestHandler(h2)` compile just fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the specification:

**15.1 Delegate declarations**

> Delegate types in C# are name equivalent, not structurally equivalent.
>   Specifically, two different delegate types that have the same
>   parameter lists and return type are considered different delegate
>   types

The first example works since you can create a new delegate from a compatible delegate instance. So while `h2` is compatible with `h1` it is not equal since they have different types:

**7.6.10.5 Delegate creation expressions**

> A delegate-creation-expression is used to create a new instance of a
>   delegate-type. delegate-creation-expression:
>
> *new delegate-type (expression)*
>
> The binding-time processing of a delegate-creation-expression of the
>   form newD(E), where D is a delegate-type and E is an expression,
>   consists of the following steps:
>
> • If E is a value, E must be compatible (§15.1) with D, and the result
>   is a reference to a newly created delegate of type D that refers to
>   the same invocation list as E. If E is not compatible with D, a
>   compile-time error occurs.